In Flutter, is there any way to get the mobile number of the android device which is running the app?
In my flutter app, I want to implement one feature, that when the app will be open, it will initially print the mobile number(considering there is single or multiple SIM card in the device) of the Android device in which the app is running.
I am not sure whether it is possible or not. If possible please let me know the details procedure with required code and configuration.
Note that: I have tried using some of the plugins/packages of flutter given below:
https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill
https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_number
https://pub.dev/packages/sim_data
But none of these solution worked for me. Please help to have a solution of this issue?

There's no way to do this for sure on Android, for a few reasons.
1)The device may not have a number.
2)Even if it does, the device may not know its own number (there are ways to set up SIM cards on phone networks where the phone doesn't).
There are calls on Android to provide that info if the phone knows it, but that doesn't mean it will always return one if the device has it.  The best way to do this is to check them, then if they don't return a value ask the user for his number.

Hello ^°^ can you accept my answer ? Thank you <3

Unfortunately, there is no way to do for now. And I think that it would be the same in the future.
BTW, alternatively, you can choose one of the following two methods if you'd like to acquire the mobile number to make a phone call.
// Method 1: Navigate to the system dial Activity.
SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
List<SubscriptionInfo> subList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList(); // supports multiple cards
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+1xxx")); // country code, e.g. +1. xxx: mobile number
intent.putExtra(SubscriptionManager.EXTRA_SUBSCRIPTION_INDEX, subList.get(0).getSimSlotIndex());
startActivity(intent);


// Method 2: Make a phone call directly.
if (checkSelfPermission("android.permission.CALL_PHONE") != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.CALL_PHONE"}, 0);
}

String primarySimId = "";
String secondarySimId = "";
SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
List<SubscriptionInfo> subList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
int index = -1;
for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : subList) {
    index++;
    if (index == 0) {
        primarySimId = subscriptionInfo.getIccId();
    } else {
        secondarySimId = subscriptionInfo.getIccId();
    }
}

TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
List<PhoneAccountHandle> list = telecomManager.getCallCapablePhoneAccounts();
PhoneAccountHandle primaryPhoneAccountHandle = null, secondaryPhoneAccountHandle = null;
for (PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle : list) {
    if (phoneAccountHandle.getId() != null && phoneAccountHandle.getId().contains(primarySimId)) {
        primaryPhoneAccountHandle = phoneAccountHandle;
    }
    if (phoneAccountHandle.getId() != null && phoneAccountHandle.getId().contains(secondarySimId)) {
        secondaryPhoneAccountHandle = phoneAccountHandle;
    }
}

// To call from SIM 1
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", "+1xxx", "");
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, primaryPhoneAccountHandle);
telecomManager.placeCall(uri, extras);

// To call from SIM 2
uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", "+1xxx", "");
extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, secondaryPhoneAccountHandle);
telecomManager.placeCall(uri, extras);

